# Sort, toggle and display array generated from array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I can only seem to get the lists to appear on the page, but clicking on the HTML buttons does not seem to display the reordered list.

Essentially I'm trying to have the HTML for each object in the array display on the page and ordered according to the functions triggered by the buttons.

**Javascript**

```
var bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic = {
    books: [
        {
            html: `<li><a href="december_2018/reviews.html">A Cage Went in Search of a Bird</a> <font id="br2">by Cary Fagan Illustrated by Banafsheh Erfanian </font></li>`,
            year: 2018,
            month: 12,
            topic: ["Children's Fiction"],
            title: `A Cage Went in Search of a Bird`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="December2013/Reviews_December_2013.html#academic">Academic Conversations</a> <font id="br2">by Jeff Zwiers and Marie Crawford</font></li>`,
            year: 2013,
            month: 12,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Academic Conversations`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="/publications/professionally_speaking/march_2019/Reviews.html">Accessible Algebra</a> <font id="br2">By Anne m. Collins and Steven r. Benson</font></li>`,
            year: 2019,
            month: 03,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Accessible Algebra`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="http://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/june_2012/resources/reviews.aspx#aboriginal">Achieving Aboriginal Student Success</a> <font id="br2">by Pamela Rose Toulouse</font></li>`,
            year: 2012,
            month: 06,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Achieving Aboriginal Student Success`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="september_2014/Reviews_September_2014.html#advocating">Advocating for English Learners</a> <font id="br2">by Diane Staehr Fenner</font></li>`,
            year: 2014,
            month: 09,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Advocating for English Learners`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="http://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/june_2013/resources/reviews.html#feilding">The Art of Fielding</a> <font id="br2">by Chad Harbach</font></li>`,
            year: 2013,
            month: 06,
            topic: ["Adult Fiction"],
            title: `The Art of Fielding`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="/publications/professionally_speaking/march_2014/Reviews_March_2014.html#assessment">Assessment in Perspective </a><font id="br2">by Clare Landrigan and Tammy Mulligan</font></li>`,
            year: 2014,
            month: 03,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Assessment in Perspective`
        }
    ]
};


var sortAlphabetical = function () {

    var listItemsAlpha = [];


    //sort by year
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.title - b.title;
    });

    //push
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        listItemsAlpha.push(bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books[i].html);
    }

    //display on site
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector("#booksList").innerHTML += listItemsAlpha[i];
    }

    console.log(listItemsAlpha)

};

var sortDate = function () {
    var listItemsDate = [];


    //sort by year
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.year - b.year;
    });

    //sort by month
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.month - b.month;
    });

    //push
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        listItemsDate.push(bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books[i].html);
    }

    //display on site
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector("#booksList").innerHTML += listItemsDate[i];
    }

    console.log(listItemsDate)
};
```

**html**

```
<button onclick="sortAlphabetical()">Alphabetical</button>
<button onclick="sortDate()">Date</button>

<div id="bookReviewsList">Book reviews by title, date and topic</div>
<div id="booksList"></div>
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Can you check browser console for any errors or logs. Whats the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `+=` without ever clearing the contents, so it's just getting appended.  Also, for strings, you can't just do `a.title - b.title`, you need to use something like `localeCompare`

```js
var bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic = {
    books: [
        {
            html: `<li><a href="december_2018/reviews.html">A Cage Went in Search of a Bird</a> <font id="br2">by Cary Fagan Illustrated by Banafsheh Erfanian </font></li>`,
            year: 2018,
            month: 12,
            topic: ["Children's Fiction"],
            title: `A Cage Went in Search of a Bird`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="December2013/Reviews_December_2013.html#academic">Academic Conversations</a> <font id="br2">by Jeff Zwiers and Marie Crawford</font></li>`,
            year: 2013,
            month: 12,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Academic Conversations`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="/publications/professionally_speaking/march_2019/Reviews.html">Accessible Algebra</a> <font id="br2">By Anne m. Collins and Steven r. Benson</font></li>`,
            year: 2019,
            month: 03,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Accessible Algebra`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="http://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/june_2012/resources/reviews.aspx#aboriginal">Achieving Aboriginal Student Success</a> <font id="br2">by Pamela Rose Toulouse</font></li>`,
            year: 2012,
            month: 06,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Achieving Aboriginal Student Success`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="september_2014/Reviews_September_2014.html#advocating">Advocating for English Learners</a> <font id="br2">by Diane Staehr Fenner</font></li>`,
            year: 2014,
            month: 09,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Advocating for English Learners`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="http://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/june_2013/resources/reviews.html#feilding">The Art of Fielding</a> <font id="br2">by Chad Harbach</font></li>`,
            year: 2013,
            month: 06,
            topic: ["Adult Fiction"],
            title: `The Art of Fielding`
        },
        {
            html: `<li><a href="/publications/professionally_speaking/march_2014/Reviews_March_2014.html#assessment">Assessment in Perspective </a><font id="br2">by Clare Landrigan and Tammy Mulligan</font></li>`,
            year: 2014,
            month: 03,
            topic: ["Adult Non Fiction"],
            title: `Assessment in Perspective`
        }
    ]
};


var sortAlphabetical = function () {

    var listItemsAlpha = [];


    //sort by year
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
    });

    //push
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        listItemsAlpha.push(bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books[i].html);
    }

    //display on site
    document.querySelector("#booksList").innerHTML = listItemsAlpha.join('\n');

};

var sortDate = function () {
    var listItemsDate = [];


    //sort by year
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.year - b.year;
    });

    //sort by month
    bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.month - b.month;
    });

    //push
    for (i = 0; i < bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books.length; i++) {
        listItemsDate.push(bookReviewsByTitleDateTopic.books[i].html);
    }

    //display on site
    document.querySelector("#booksList").innerHTML = listItemsDate.join('\n');
};
```

```html
<button onclick="sortAlphabetical()">Alphabetical</button>
<button onclick="sortDate()">Date</button>

<div id="bookReviewsList">Book reviews by title, date and topic</div>
<div id="booksList"></div>
```